# A formula, which should return 0, is returning a negative number

Tags: c#, formula, rgb, hue

```
hue = (int)Math.Round(60 * ((double)(r - g) / sat + 4));
```

This is setting hue to -2147483288, when the values for r, g and sat are all zeroes. Any help appreciated! EDIT: This is C#

Comment: If r, g, and sat == 0, then you are dividing by zero.

Comment: what do you expect as a result of expression `(0-0)/0`?

Comment: Why do you think this should be 0?

Comment: It shouldn't return `0`, It should throw `DivideByZeroException`

Comment: Selman22: Not really. When doubles are in play, this exception is never raised. The results are as follows: positive number divided by zero in doubles -> Double.PositiveInfinity ; zero divided by zero -> Double.NaN; negative number divided by zero in doubles -> Double.NegativeInfinity.

Answer (score 4):

You're dividing by 0.  i.e. sat is 0.  Definitely not recommended in any programming language.  You'll want to have a special case when sat = 0:

```
if(sat==0)
    hue = 0;
else
    hue = (int)Math.Round(60 * ((double)(r - g) / sat + 4));
```

Comment: @GrantWinney since 0 + 4 isn't wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: @GrantWinney  I'm not sure where you think I'm stating that

Comment: Thank you all! I didn't know that 0/0 didn't equal 0 in programming languages :P

Comment: @user3217178, 0/0 is never 0 anywhere :)

Comment: @user3217178 it's not just in programming, [division by zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero) is undefined in most fields of mathematics.

Comment: @p.s.w.g he probably meant it as as a joke - considering the smiley.

Comment: @user3217178 Glad to be of help.  If you're happy with my answer, it would be great if you accepted it :)

Answer (score 2):

What happens on the right-hand side is that you are performing a divison by zero. That is not reported as an exception because you are using doubles, and for these zero division is allowed, but will not produce "nice" and "meaningful" results. Especially if you are further performing calculations and converting the result to int.

How this works for doubles example:

- 1.0 divided by 0.0 -> Double.PositiveInfinity
- 0.0 divided by 0.0 -> Double.NaN (not-a-number)
- -1.0 divided by 0.0 -> Double.NegativeInfinity

This is standard behavior defined in IEEE-754, most programming languages should behave this way.